# magento2 still serves files from root/pub/ directory even in dev mode

Tags: magento2, javascript, workflow

App mode is developer (checked also in env file).

Nginx has root `www/`.

`www/index.php` is hit.

Placed a `die()` statement in `www/pub/index.php` to make sure that the file isn't hit. It is not hit.

But if I look into page source, css and js are still served from pub folder.

In admin I have selected client side workflow.

So if I have some js in my module, I have to edit the js in `pub/` and then copy my changes to app when done, which is quite a pain.

I don't know about any other settings that I can check.

`grunt watch` picks up less files but doesn't do anything to js files (I don't know if this is the intended behaviour).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that `.htaccess` and other files were missing from `pub/static` folder. After I added the whole pub folder from https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/develop/pub and made sure the user and permissions are ok, the dev mode is now working as expected.